# Can't access web.py sessions when using web.ctx.session

Tags: web.py

I have my views, models and url stored in a module which is then imported by my app.py where the session store is setup. Using my views I can set a session variable by following the guidelines described here http://webpy.org/cookbook/sessions_with_subapp but I can't access the value of my session once it's set I get this exception

```
AttributeError: 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'session'
```

this is my app.py - I'm using livereload to simplify the development process which works like a sharm

```
from livereload import Server

import web

from nestpas.views import *
from nestpas.urls import *
import sys

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)


app = web.application(urls, globals())
webapp = app.wsgifunc()

# Setup session storage
db = web.database(dbn='sqlite', db='dev.db')
store = web.session.DBStore(db, 'sessions')
session = web.session.Session(app, store,
    initializer={'auth': 0}
)

def session_hook():
    web.ctx.session = session

app.add_processor(web.loadhook(session_hook))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    static_app = web.httpserver.StaticMiddleware(webapp)
    server = Server(static_app)
    server.watch('static/', 'templates/', 'nestpas/')
    server.serve(port=8080, host='localhost')
```

here is how I set the session value

```
class Login:
    def GET(self):
        """ Login """
        render = web.template.render(base="admin")
        return render.login({})

    def POST(self):
        """ Handle login """
        inp = web.input()
        if 'user_mail' in inp and 'user_pwd' in inp:
            try:
                user = User.get(
                    User.mail == inp.user_mail,
                    User.password == inp.user_pwd
                )
                logging.info("Login by user {}".format(user.id))
                web.ctx.session.auth = 1
                logging.warn(web.ctx.session.auth) # Shows the value

                raise web.seeother("/admin/")
            except DoesNotExist:
                logging.warning("Login attempt")
                raise web.seeother("/login/")   
        else:
            raise web.seeother("/login/")
```

Here is how I try to access the value of the session

```
def authenticate(klass):
    logging.warn("- hello Kitty {}".format(
        web.ctx.session.auth
    ))
    return klass

@authenticate
class Admin:
    def GET(self):
        """ Admin """
        posts = BlogPost.select().order_by(
                BlogPost.when_created.desc()
            ).paginate(0, 10)

        render = web.template.render(base="admin")
        return render.latest({
            "user_mail": "Kitty",
            "blog_posts": posts
        })
```

I also tried web.ctx.session.get() and web.ctx.session['auth'] and web.ctx['session'] but none of them work.

Im on mac with web.py==0.40.dev0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session has no value at the class level, so using a decorator on a class won't work. You can use a decorator on your `def GET(self)` (you'd have to change your `authenticate()` a bit, but it's the same idea.)

Comment: Oh dang, I was hoping I could do it using a class decorator, so I need a method decorator instead?

Comment: Yes, method decorator.